# Swift Scroll for the view if text is bigger in height

Tags: ios, swift, text

[image]

So right now if the text doesn't fit there it adds a scrollbar to the "text view", but what I want is instead is to display the whole text scroll down on the entire view not only that section.

I'm new to the swift and xcode world, so if you guys can point me in the right direction that will help.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your problem, But What I get from what you say, could be achieved using a TextView instead of a Label.

Comment: I have a TextView already, I want to use something else than a textview, something where you can scroll the entire view and you can read the text, same thing when you scroll on your news feed on facebook app for eg

Comment: There is something on iOS called Scroll View, With that you can do it. Other way is using a Table View and manage each cell as your content.

Comment: Ok I got. You can simply use NSAttributedString with UILabel. You only have to apply autolayout for UILabel with "number of lines = 0"